# Implementing counter-steering for a drifting car in 2D

Tags: unity, 2d, car

I could make a sliding car. but i want the counter steer functionality. My current model of the car has 4 wheels, all of them have a script handling the slip. am currently multiplying the side ways velocity by a value between 0 and 1 (like 0.6 while it's sticky and 0.9 while it's sliding).

In the beginning all my wheels had a mass of 1 so the car was sliding really fast and spinning like crazy. When i increased the mass to 20 each the car slides normally. But the front part of the car doesn't move sideways at all when i counter steer.

This is the code i have right now for each tire

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class wheel : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Controls controls_i;
    private Rigidbody2D rigid_body;
    private Vector2 current_velocity;
    public bool rotate, power;
    public int rotation_angle, acceleration, max_speed;
    public float max_friction, min_friction, max_slip;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        controls_i = GameObject.Find("Main_camera").GetComponent<Controls>();
        rigid_body = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void set_angle(float angle){
        angle = Utils.linear_range(45, -45, rotation_angle, -rotation_angle, angle);
        Vector3 tmp = transform.localEulerAngles;
        tmp.z = angle;
        transform.localEulerAngles = tmp;
    }
    void accelerate(float acceleration){
        if(current_velocity.y < max_speed){
            rigid_body.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.up * acceleration);
        }
    }
    // void apply_sideways_friction(){
    //     float sideways_velocity = current_velocity.x;
    //     float velocity_sign = Mathf.Sign(sideways_velocity);
    //     sideways_velocity = Mathf.Abs(sideways_velocity);
    //     float slip = sideways_velocity - max_friction;

    //     float updated_velocity = 0;
    //     if(slip > 0){
    //         slip = sideways_velocity - Utils.curve_map_linear(0, max_slip, min_friction, max_friction, slip, -1);
    //         updated_velocity = slip;
    //     }

    //     Vector2 new_velocity = transform.TransformVector(new Vector2(velocity_sign * updated_velocity, current_velocity.y));
    //     rigid_body.velocity = new_velocity;
    // }

    public float slip_threshold, stick_threshold;
    public float slip_drag, stick_drag;
    public bool slipping = false;
    void apply_sideways_friction(){
        if(!slipping && (Mathf.Abs(current_velocity.x) >= (slip_threshold * max_speed))){
            slipping = true;
        }else if(slipping && (Mathf.Abs(current_velocity.x) <= (stick_threshold * max_speed))){
            slipping = false;
        }
        float drag = slipping ? slip_drag : stick_drag;
        float new_slip_velocity = current_velocity.x * drag;
        Vector2 new_velocity = transform.TransformVector(new Vector2(new_slip_velocity, current_velocity.y));
        rigid_body.velocity = new_velocity;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        current_velocity = transform.InverseTransformVector(rigid_body.velocity); 
        Debug.Log("* " + gameObject.name + " | " + transform.InverseTransformVector(rigid_body.velocity));

        if(rotate){
            set_angle(controls_i.getSteeringAngle());
        }

        apply_sideways_friction();

        if(power){
            accelerate(acceleration);
        }
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, (Vector2)transform .position + rigid_body.velocity, Color.red, Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " | " + transform.InverseTransformVector(rigid_body.velocity));
    }
}
```

Am looking for something like in the game "absolute drift"

I have tried wheel colliders too. But the same problem occurred there, the car slides but couldn't get counter steer drift to work.

basically, the the player doesn't have speed control. the car will accelerate to a max speed on its own, slowly. The player can steer the car. When the player steers the car left or right, when the sideways momentum increases to a certain level, I want the car to slowly start skidding and if the player doesn't counter steer the car will spin and stop, then accelerate again. If he does counter steer at the right moment I want the car to drift. I don't wanna code the exact drift logic like if speed =n and steering angle = x for y seconds add force to the front part of the car. cos I want the user to try and get into a drift and control it by steering left and right to keep the car in drift.

Comment: Assume your reader hasn't played Absolute Drift. What specific qualities does this game's drifting have that you want to introduce to your game? Try walking through an example "When the player does X, the car moves like Y..."

Comment: I have edited to add some information about the expectations. Is there anything else i can do to better my question.